# php - preg_replace / backreference - Syntax to extract parts from mail address

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I do have a var like this:

```
$mail_from = "Firstname Lastname <email@domain.com>";
```

I would like to receive either an

```
array(name=>"firstname lastname", email=>"email@domain.com")
or 
the values in two separate vars ($name = "...", $email = "...")
```

I have been playing around with preg_replace but somehow do not get it done ...

Did extensive search but did not find a way to get this done.

This is the closest I got:

```
$str = 'My First Name <email@domain.com>';
preg_match('~(?:"([^"]*)")?\s*(.*)~',$str,$var);
print_r($var);
echo "<br>Name: ".$var[0];
echo "<br>Mail: ".$var[2];
```

How do I get "email@domain.com" into $var['x]?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you get there? Your source string doesn't contain double quotes. You should rather make the regex scan for `<` angle `>` brackets. As alternative to a custom regex try [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses`](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses) or [`Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList()`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-rfc822.parseaddresslist.php)

Comment: Current Output:
Array ( [0] => My First Name [1] => [2] => My First Name )
Name: My First Name
Mail: My First Name

Comment: @mario - that would be perfect - unfortunately mailparse is not installed :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example and should always work, when the email is within angle brackets.

```
$str = 'My First Name <email@domain.com>';
preg_match('~(?:([^<]*?)\s*)?<(.*)>~', $str, $var);
print_r($var);
echo "<br>Name: ".$var[1];
echo "<br>Mail: ".$var[2];
```

**Explanation:**

`(?:([^<]*?)\s*)?` matches optionally everything that is not a `<` and everything except the trailing whitespace is stored in group 1.

`<(.*)>` matches something between angle brackets and store it in group 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //trythis
 $mail_from = "Firstname Lastname <email@domain.com>";
 $a = explode("<", $mail_from);
 $b=str_replace(">","",$a[1]);
 $c=$a[0];
 echo $b;
 echo $c;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`(?<=")([^"<>]+?) *<([^<>"]+)>(?=")`

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?<=")([^"<>]+?) *<([^<>"]+)>(?=")

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=")»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^"<>]+?)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “"<>” «[^"<>]+?»
      Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
Match the character “ ” literally « *»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “<” literally «<»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([^<>"]+)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>"” «[^<>"]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “>” literally «>»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=")»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
-->
```

**Code:**

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=")([^"<>]+?) *<([^<>"]+)>(?=")/m', '<br>Name:$1<br>Mail:$2', $subject);
```

---

Comment: Hi Cylian, thanks. But your Script also o´nly returnes the sender name (Firstname Lastname), not the mail address.

Comment: Sender name comes within ``$1``, where as mail address comes within ``$2``.